# Testing model using a directory on keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

So I've trained a CNN using the keras library, specifically using the `.flow_from_directory()` method, where my images are stored in `training_set`, `validation_set` and `test_set` folders, but I can't find a way to test the `test_set` folder.

Do I have to create a .csv file?

I've tried using `model.evaluate()`, but that doesn't seem to work using images stored in classification folders. Thanks in advance for the helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `evaluate_generator` function. You can use the same `flow_from_directory` to provide the generator as the first argument to this function.

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(...)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(...)
model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, ...)
```

Comment: @gabriel, accepting / upvoting answer is appreciated if it helped you.

Comment: Done. Stack won't show that I upvoted you yet (not enough rep), but it's there.

Comment: evaluate_generator is deprecated, you should use evaluate method instead. Here is a good example about its usage, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63950899/2234161